# ASP.Net Web API 2 async method fails for JSON response

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I have below async method in Web API 2:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public async Task<TestResultResponse> GetAll()
{
    DBService repo = new DBService();
    TestResultResponse response = new TestResultResponse();

    response.Tests = await repo.GetAll(); // call to async method

    return response;
}
```

This API method works fine if request content type is XML ,i.e, response is returned in XML format. However, when I try to get JSON response, I get StackOverflow exception. In VS 2013, I get only below details as part of exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

I get this exception only when I request for response in JSON. It works fine for XML response. For sync methods, JSON works fine. It seems to be issue only with JSON and aync methods.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error for JSON response ?

**Update 1:** As requested below is list of classes used for response:

```
public class TestResultResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

public class Test : BaseEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Content { get; set; }    
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Test InnerDoc { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }    
    public int Status { get; set; }    
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }    
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }    
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can find XML response at http://pastebin.com/Ys7DeZPc

Comment: Could you post the ** TestResultResponse** class definition?

Comment: What do your objects look like? I'm guessing you're having a cyclic dependency somewhere.

Comment: I'm guessing for a cyclic dependency as well. Perhaps the default XML serializer has a lower MaxDepth property set than the JSON counterpart (`HttpConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter/XmlFormatter.MaxDepth`)

Comment: Here's a good post with different ways to handle circular references: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Loop-Reference-handling-in-caaffaf7

Comment: With respect to circular references it seems fine (unless `ObjectId` has it which seems unlikely) and it still wouldn't explain why it works in the synchronous case. Tip 1: create a test project that runs the above action method code but without Web API and serialize by hand. Tip 2: try with another JSON serializer.

Comment: What happens if you switch to [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)?  That XML was generated by `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Set [`JsonSerializerSettings.MaxDepth`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MaxDepth.htm) to something small, say 50, and see where the exception is thrown.